# Getting the sum of the column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, identity-column

I am using user Keevas' example, but asking a different question....

```
select Master_Code, SUM(Jan), SUM(Feb), SUM(Mar)
 from dbo.foobar
WHERE Participating_City = 'foofoo'
GROUP BY Master_Code ORDER BY Master_Code ASC
```

something like this:

```
Master_Code sum(Jan) Sum(Feb) sum(Mar)  Total
        1     4         5       4        13
        2     5         5       5        15
```

How do I get Total value column?

Comment: read something about `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: You may refer on this link: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT username,SUM(value) AS SumValue FROM
 table GROUP BY username ORDER BY SumValue DESC
```